# how to footer of wordpress this line

Tags: wordpress

how to remove

```
Powered by WordPress | Designed by: SharePoint Site | Thanks to Virtual Server, Email Hosting and Rent Server
```

in WordPress theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to your Wordpress admin page and in style, you will have "Editor". In right menu, select "footer.php" In my case it looks like this:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="clearfix">
    <p>Proudly powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s', 'yoko' ), 'Yoko', '<a href="http://www.elmastudio.de/wordpress-themes/">Elmastudio</a>' ); ?>
    </p>
    <a href="#page" class="top"><?php _e( 'Top', 'yoko' ); ?></a>
</footer>
```

So here you can do the edits as you want